# were can I find the Greenwich equilibrium argument for tidal prediction(Vo+u)?

Tags: tides

the closest i've got was with a table in the following manual that only went up to the year 2000.
https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/publications/SpecialPubNo98.pdf

Comment: If you can use matlab, then there is the t_tide package (https://www.eoas.ubc.ca/~rich/#T_Tide) that will provide it. In Python, you can try utide: https://pypi.org/project/UTide/